# What can I add to my code to show in the output all the movements that the sorting has made?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

What I wanted for my code was to show all the movements that the sorting has made. For my other codes such as Bubble Sort, Insertion and Selection, I successfully printed all the passes for it. But when I tried it on my code Merge, the output prints the sorted array only in multiple times.

```py
def mergeSort(nums):
    if len(nums) > 1:
        mid = len(nums) // 2
        left = nums[:mid]
        right = nums[mid:]

        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0

        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
                nums[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                nums[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
        while i < len(left):
            nums[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while j < len(right):
            nums[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

nums = [9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
n = len(nums)
for i in range(n):
    mergeSort(nums)
    print(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

The print function is placed after you have sorted the list, therefore, it is printing only the sorted list.
So basically just, put print somewhere inside the code, like

```
def mergeSort(nums):
    if len(nums) > 1:
        mid = len(nums) // 2
        left = nums[:mid]
        right = nums[mid:]    
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0

        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
                nums[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                nums[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
        while i < len(left):
            nums[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while j < len(right):
            nums[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

nums = [9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
n = len(nums)
for i in range(n):
    mergeSort(nums)
print(nums)
```

Gives:

```
[9]
[7]
[7, 9]
[5]
[3]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[1]
[3]
[1, 3]
[5]
[7]
[9]
[7, 9]
[5, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[1]
[3]
[1, 3]
[5]
[7]
[9]
[7, 9]
[5, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[1]
[3]
[1, 3]
[5]
[7]
[9]
[7, 9]
[5, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[1]
[3]
[1, 3]
[5]
[7]
[9]
[7, 9]
[5, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: You didn't add `print` inside the loop.

Comment: Where should I insert the print function?